# Tag Cleanup: fixing [serial] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Here are various posts I've modified the tag [serial](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial) on.  It's an incredibly broad tag that should be used with great care so as to avoid becoming totally meaningless (if not already). Vent disagreement here.

- Only tangentially related. [icp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icp)/[icsp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icsp) would be better, but they don't exist.

  - [Serial programmer not working, what are the possible problem sources?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/serial-programmer-not-working-what-are-the-possible-problem-sources)
  - [Programming Atmega with serial port](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/programming-atmega-with-serial-portIt) already has [programmer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programmer) which is reasonably specific.
- The question is *about* an [lcd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcd) module.  The fact it uses a serial interface is secondary.

  - [Need bin or hex file for Pic 16F648A Serial LCD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10063/need-bin-or-hex-file-for-pic-16f648a-serial-lcd)
- Arduino "Serial" = UART software/hardware module

  - [RFID Reader coding](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9761/rfid-reader-coding)
  - [Can I use an Arduino as a USB to serial interface?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9293/arduino-as-serial-console)
  - [Serial communication and reading byte arrays with Arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/serial-communication-and-reading-byte-arrays-with-arduino)
- Overbroad

  - [ATtiny V-USB with 115200bps? DIP only](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8969/attiny-v-usb-with-115200bps-dip-only)
  - [Small "FTDI"-like chip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/small-ftdi-like-chip)
  - [How can I control 128 (or more) solenoids?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/how-can-i-control-128-or-more-solenoids) (serial, parallel, multiplexing...better known as: multiplexing.)

Answer (score 1):

- [Need bin or hex file for Pic 16F648A Serial LCD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10063/need-bin-or-hex-file-for-pic-16f648a-serial-lcd)

  - Good to get rid of [serial](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial) (especially since it's a parallel interface!).
  - Think it needs other tags, like [library](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) and [pic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pic). (May even qualify for the fiendish [software](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tag, but let's not go there.) What do you think?
- [RFID Reader coding](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/9761/2118)

  - We never heard back as to whether this was via USB or RS232('ish).
- [Small "FTDI"-like chip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/6891/2118)

  - Don't think this needs any mention of either *UART* or *serial*, though I think the [serial](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial) is slightly more relevant, as an FTDI is really a USB-to-RS232 or USB-to-FIFO device. This post is really about voltage conversion ([level-shifting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/level-shifting)) and surface-mount package selection (doesn't quality for [smd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smd) though, in my opinion, as it's not generally about surface mount, but a subset of it).
- [How can I control 128 (or more) solenoids?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/how-can-i-control-128-or-more-solenoids)

  - I've never thought of multiplexing as including serial, but I think this makes sense, especially when considering time-domain multiplexing -- this is basically serial windows. Would have recommended both [mux](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mux) and [serial](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial), but just [mux](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mux) makes sense with this clarification. ***Will it make sense to others?*** Can a wiki help?

Comment: That FTDI chips have a synchronous serial engine is a red herring.  That question is clearly about UART functionality, and only UART.

Comment: That first question is about serial - about as much as it is about LCDs. He want's a canned program ROM for a serial->LCD converter.